# How to redirect to particular url from jsp page of liferay on basis of condition if and else?

Tags: jsp, redirect, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have override the login.jsp file of liferay

```
<%--
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2000-2012 Liferay, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
 * Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
 * any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more
 * details.
 */
--%>

<%@ include file="/html/portlet/login/init.jsp" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/html/portlet/login/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/html/portlet/login/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/html/portlet/login/css/blue.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/html/portlet/login/css/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/html/portlet/login/css/jquery.qtip.min.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="<%= themeDisplay.isSignedIn() %>">

        <%
        String signedInAs = HtmlUtil.escape(user.getFullName());

        if (themeDisplay.isShowMyAccountIcon()) {
            signedInAs = "<a href=\"" + HtmlUtil.escape(themeDisplay.getURLMyAccount().toString()) + "\">" + signedInAs + "</a>";
        }
        %>
        <%= LanguageUtil.format(pageContext, "you-are-signed-in-as-x", signedInAs, false) %>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <%
        String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(request, "redirect");

        String login = LoginUtil.getLogin(request, "login", company);
        String password = StringPool.BLANK;
        boolean rememberMe = ParamUtil.getBoolean(request, "rememberMe");

        if (Validator.isNull(authType)) {
            authType = company.getAuthType();
        }
        %>

        <portlet:actionURL secure="<%= PropsValues.COMPANY_SECURITY_AUTH_REQUIRES_HTTPS || request.isSecure() %>" var="loginURL">
            <portlet:param name="saveLastPath" value="0" />
            <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/login" />
            <portlet:param name="doActionAfterLogin" value="<%= portletName.equals(PortletKeys.FAST_LOGIN) ? Boolean.TRUE.toString() : Boolean.FALSE.toString() %>" />
        </portlet:actionURL>

        <aui:form action="<%= loginURL %>" autocomplete='<%= PropsValues.COMPANY_SECURITY_LOGIN_FORM_AUTOCOMPLETE ? "on" : "off" %>' method="post" name="fm">
            <aui:input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<%= redirect %>" />

            <c:choose>
                <c:when test='<%= SessionMessages.contains(request, "user_added") %>'>

                    <%
                    String userEmailAddress = (String)SessionMessages.get(request, "user_added");
                    String userPassword = (String)SessionMessages.get(request, "user_added_password");
                    %>
                    <div class="portlet-msg-success">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="<%= company.isStrangersVerify() || Validator.isNull(userPassword) %>">
                                <%= LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "thank-you-for-creating-an-account") %>

                                <c:if test="<%= company.isStrangersVerify() %>">
                                    <%= LanguageUtil.format(pageContext, "your-email-verification-code-has-been-sent-to-x", userEmailAddress) %>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <%= LanguageUtil.format(pageContext, "thank-you-for-creating-an-account.-your-password-is-x", userPassword, false) %>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>

                        <c:if test="<%= PrefsPropsUtil.getBoolean(company.getCompanyId(), PropsKeys.ADMIN_EMAIL_USER_ADDED_ENABLED) %>">
                            <%= LanguageUtil.format(pageContext, "your-password-has-been-sent-to-x", userEmailAddress) %>
                        </c:if>
                    </div>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test='<%= SessionMessages.contains(request, "user_pending") %>'>

                    <%
                    String userEmailAddress = (String)SessionMessages.get(request, "user_pending");
                    %>

                    <div class="portlet-msg-success">
                        <%= LanguageUtil.format(pageContext, "thank-you-for-creating-an-account.-you-will-be-notified-via-email-at-x-when-your-account-has-been-approved", userEmailAddress) %>
                    </div>
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>

            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= AuthException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CompanyMaxUsersException.class %>" message="unable-to-login-because-the-maximum-number-of-users-has-been-reached" />
            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CookieNotSupportedException.class %>" message="authentication-failed-please-enable-browser-cookies" />
            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= NoSuchUserException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= PasswordExpiredException.class %>" message="your-password-has-expired" />
            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserEmailAddressException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserLockoutException.class %>" message="this-account-has-been-locked" />
            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserPasswordException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />
            <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserScreenNameException.class %>" message="authentication-failed" />

            <aui:fieldset>

                <%
                String loginLabel = null;
                if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_EA)) {
                    loginLabel = "";
                }
                else if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_SN)) {
                    loginLabel = "screen-name";
                }
                else if (authType.equals(CompanyConstants.AUTH_TYPE_ID)) {
                    loginLabel = "id";
                }
                %>                      
                <span id="<portlet:namespace />passwordCapsLockSpan" style="display: none;"><liferay-ui:message key="caps-lock-is-on" /></span>

                <div class="login_page">
                    <div class="login_box">     
                        <form id="login_form">
                            <div class="top_b">Sign in</div>    
                            <div class="alert alert-info alert-login">
                                Login with your Username and Password
                            </div>
                            <div class="cnt_b">
                                <div class="formRow">
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span style="float:left;" class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                        <aui:input label="" style="width:210px;" name="login" showRequiredLabel="<%= false %>" type="text" value="">                                
                                        </aui:input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formRow">
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span style="float:left;" class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <aui:input label="" style="width:210px;" name="password" showRequiredLabel="<%= false %>" type="password" value="<%= password %>">                              
                                        </aui:input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formRow clearfix" style='margin-top:0;'>
                                    <c:if test="<%= company.isAutoLogin() && !PropsValues.SESSION_DISABLED %>">
                                        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked="<%= rememberMe %>" name="rememberMe"/> Remember me</label>
                                    </c:if>                     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btm_b clearfix">                                    
                                <aui:button-row>

                                    <aui:button style="float:right;" class="btn btn-inverse pull-right" type="submit" value="sign-in" />                                    
                                </aui:button-row>                                                   
                            </div>  
                        </form>                 
                    </div>      
                </div>          
            </aui:fieldset>         
        </aui:form>                         
        <c:if test="<%= windowState.equals(WindowState.MAXIMIZED) %>">
            <aui:script>
                Liferay.Util.focusFormField(document.<portlet:namespace />fm.<portlet:namespace />login);
            </aui:script>
        </c:if>

        <aui:script use="aui-base">
            var password = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />password');
            if (password) {
                password.on(
                    'keypress',
                    function(event) {
                        Liferay.Util.showCapsLock(event, '<portlet:namespace />passwordCapsLockSpan');
                    }
                );
            }
        </aui:script>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Above is my login.jsp now problem am facing is when i used to delete history and then when i refresh the page its just giving me one label as "Your Signing in As " :user name

But how can i prevent this that when user clear the history then its should be redirect to login page rather then this page as m getting now...i jst want to know how can i redirect to c/portal/login url from jsp page itself?

Comment: Can you check if in ROOT.war/WEB-INF/web.xml, you have `Auto Login Filter` entry and `url-pattern` is `/c/portal/login` ?

Comment: <login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>PortalRealm</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
   <form-login-page>/c/portal/j_login</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/c/portal/j_login_error</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
 </login-config>..this is what i got in my web.xml

Comment: Apart from that, I have this entry...  `<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Auto Login Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/c/portal/login</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>`  `<filter>
  <filter-name>Auto Login Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>`

Comment: so i need to add this lines in my web.xml..whats this lines will do...can u please explain?